# Как обработать записи полей MySQL и вернуть результат в другое поле посредством PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица os_test,где 3 поля: id, pos, name.Поле name изначально пустое,мне надо с помощью PHP скрипта взять значение pos,обработать и записать его в name.Логика подсказывает,но не знания,что нужно выбирать по id,считывать значение pos,обрабатывать и записывать эти значения в name,и все это в цикле,но как это делать не знаю,поэтому и обращаюсь к вам. Спасибо.

Comment: Все зависит от того, как именно надо обработать pos. В некоторых случаях это можно сделать средствами mysql.

Comment: надо передать в функцию,перевода в транслит

Answer (score 2):

Проходим построчно по всей таблице, обрабатываем значение `pos` функцией `translit` и Записываем `name` в базу.

`translit` - это ваша функция.

```
/*** соединяемся с бд ***/
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `os_test`');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $name = translit($row['pos']);
    mysql_query('UPDATE `os_test` SET name = \''.$name.'\' WHERE id = '.$row['id']);
}
 /*** закрываем соединение ***/
```

Comment: Пишу и ничего не происходит

    function ru2Lat($string)
    {
        return ($string);
    }
    $host     = 'localhost';
    $database = 'test';
    $user     = 'root';
    $pswd     = '';
    
    $dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM os_test');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $name = ru2Lat($res['pos']);
        mysql_query('UPDATE os_test SET name = ' . $name . ' WHERE id = ' . $res['id']);
    }

Comment: поправил ответ.

по запарке внутри `while` использовал `res` вместо `row`

Answer (score 0):

Выбираем все записи из таблицы.

пробегаешь по всем записям

```
*цикл*
$row=mysql_fetch_array();
и UPDATE SET name=pos WHERE id = $row['id'] ну тут правильно написать нужно.
*цикл*
```

Ну и все, это если в цикле по всем записям пробежаться, но можно сделать и иначе.

Comment: честно,как-то не понятно мне

Comment: Честно нужно просто иногда думать :)

Вот я поражаюсь.

Иногда немного подумать и вписать цикл в готовый ответ у ТС не хватает, и не хватает непонятно чего. Ума, сил, лень мешает.

Собственно если и выше написанный ответ, получивший 1 голос и ты пишешь что

>пишу и ничего не происходит

тут все-таки дело в ТС. Правильно нужно хотя бы списывать.

Comment: может ума и не так много,но попробуйте вначале написать внятно и разборчиво,а не так: "...ну тут правильно написать нужно."
если я не могу ответить то не буду писать так

Comment: Написано так чтобы ТС мог сам немного пошевелить головой, поискать, а не говорить:"Да не получается у меня, дайте рабочий код в конце-то концов!"